# $w=(\frac{1+z}{1-z})^2$ maps the disk $|z|\lt 1$ onto the plane, excluding the ray $(u,0), u\le 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

$w=(\frac{1+z}{1-z})^2$ maps the disk $|z|\lt 1$ onto the plane, excluding the ray $(u,0), u\le 0$.

I've tried many different ways. Writing down the function in terms of polar coordinates, seeing it as a square of a fractional linear equation, writing down it as a real and complex function, but have failed to show the conclusion. What can I do to find the image? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

The map $$\varphi(z)=\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^2$$ is the function composition of the homography $\varphi_1(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ and of the map $\varphi_2(z)=z^2$. $\varphi_2$ transforms the open half plane of complexes having positive real part into the plane excluding the ray.

You have then to use results regarding complex homographies to see how circles centered at the origin are transformed by $\varphi_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=(1+z)^2/(1-z)^2$ for $z\ne 1.$ We have $f(0)=1.$ Now for $w\ne 1$ and $w$  not on the non-negative real ray, let $w=v^2.$ We have $v\ne \pm 1.$ And we have  $$w=f(z)\iff \pm v=(1+z)/(1-z)\iff (\;z=(v-1)/(v+1) \lor z=(v+1)/(v-1)\;).$$ Now $$|v+1|\ne |v-1|.$$ Geometrically, if $|v-1|=|v+1|$ then $v$ is equidistant to $1$ and  to $-1,$ which puts $v$ on the imaginary axis, but this puts $w=v^2$ on the non-negative real ray. So let $z=(v-1)/(v+1)$ if $|v+1|>|v-1|,$ and let $z=(v+1)/(v-1)$ if $|v-1|>|v+1|.$ Then $|z|<1$ and $f(z)=w.$